# Installing App Engine Results fails with SHA1 verification

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nitrousio

I'm trying to set up my python instance with app engine, but I'm getting an error:

```
action@kings-landing-python-98539:~$ parts install googleappengine                                                                                                                                             => Downloading https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.0.zip...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   127  100   127    0     0    343      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   447
parts: ERROR: SHA1 verification failed
Aborting!
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in the nitrousio [googleappengine package](https://github.com/nitrous-io/autoparts/blob/master/lib/autoparts/packages/googleappengine.rb) returns an XML error, which obviously doesn't match the sha1sum of the SDK. The latest version can be downloaded from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads). If their package system is the only way to get things installed with nitrous (I've never used it), then you could submit a bug-report to get them to update the spec.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thanks. I've submitted a pull request to them to update the URL for the new version...